# Perl IPC::Open3 and bash -s: Can I differentiate STDIN between bash and its children?

Tags: bash, perl

I am using open3 to invoke "bash -s --" and I am then sending commands to that STDIN File handle. But I would like commands that are then called by this bash instance not to be able to read from the same STDIN. This is the program's basic structure:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;

my ($SCRIN, $SCROUT, $SCRERR, $CPID);
my $CMDS='
  echo start
  cat $FILE
  echo done with cat
  exit 0
';


$CPID=open3($SCRIN, $SCROUT, $SCRERR, 'exec -a testshell /bin/bash -s -- param1');

print $SCRIN $CMDS;

print STDOUT $_ while (<$SCROUT>);
```

As the "$CMDS" part is actually quite variable, I sometimes have the problem of a hang, as in the case above when "$FILE" is not set in the environment, because "cat" does then read STDIN and reads "echo done with cat\nexit 0", and the shell never terminates.

My question is now: Can I use a different FD to feed the commands to bash than the one that commands inside that bash read their STDIN from? I would figure, that input redirection from a different FD would affect all stages, but maybe bash can be manipulated not to read from STDIN but from a different FD; I just did not find a way.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: You'll need to use the [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.94/lib/IPC/Run.pm) module instead of Open3. It provides a lot of advanced options including the ability to create as many different pipes as you need connected to different child file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for hint. Still, the question remains: Can I "feed" the commands (=a shell script) to bash without those commands executed by bash "reading away" those? I have no idea how to make that possible even with IPC::Run ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl has no idea from where the bash will read it's input. Therefore you need handle this at the `bash` level - with some rederections.

And because you said:

> > As the "$CMDS" part is actually quite variable,

so, you haven't control about the actual bash script what you will execute, the easy way is *wrap* the script in something what is under your control.

Using [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)'s synopsis (what is much more user-friendly) as IPC::Open3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use IPC::Run qw(run timeout);
my($out, $err);
my @bash = qw(/bin/bash -s -- param1 param2 param3);

my $CMDS=<<'EOF';
    echo "ARGS: $@"
    echo ==in bash the env FILE is: ${FILE:-undef}==
    cat $FILE
    date
    exit 0
EOF

#the wrapper - redirect the bash subshell's stdin from /dev/null    
my $wrapper = "( $CMDS ) </dev/null";

say "ENV{FILE}:", $ENV{FILE}//"undef";
run \@bash, \$wrapper, \$out, \$err, timeout(10) or die "error: $?";
say $out;

$ENV{FILE} = "./testfile"; #set the environment variable FILE
say "ENV{FILE}:", $ENV{FILE}//"undef";
run \@bash, \$wrapper, \$out, \$err, timeout(10) or die "error: $?";
say $out;
```

running it as

```
seq 5 > testfile
perl script.pl
```

prints

```
ENV{FILE}:undef
ARGS: param1 param2 param3
==in bash the env FILE is: undef==
Fri Mar  6 14:31:44 CET 2015

ENV{FILE}:./testfile
ARGS: param1 param2 param3
==in bash the env FILE is: ./testfile==
1
2
3
4
5
Fri Mar  6 14:31:44 CET 2015
```

So, it works with defined env variable FILE or without.

Comment: It is true that I don't have control about the actual script, but of course I can just prefix and postfix the $CMDS as I want. I have to use open3 because I also use with with Net::OpenSSH, which provides a "remote open3", and from your post I now understood that I just have to prefix $CMDS with '(' and postfix it with ') </dev/null'. The perfect solution to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you should simply pass the commands as an argument instead of via STDIN.

```
open(local *SCRIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;

open3($SCRIN, $SCROUT, $SCRERR,
   'exec', '-a', 'testshell', '/bin/bash', '-c', $CMDS, '--', 'param1');
```

---

The fact that you have multiple commands separated by newlines is not a problem for `-c`.

```
$ bash -c '
   echo foo
   echo "$1"
   echo baz
' -- bar
foo
bar
baz
```

---

It's not a problem if `$CMDS` contains shell characters.

```
$ perl
   use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

   my $CMDS = q{
      echo '$1'
      echo "$1"
   };

   my @args = q{Foo's Bar};

   open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
   waitpid(open3('<&CHILD_STDIN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR',
      'bash', '-c', $CMDS, '--', @args), 0);
^D
$1
Foo's Bar
```

Comment: It seems that this is difficult to handle with multiline $CMDS, otherwise it looks like a clear and simple solution. Thank you!

Comment: `-c` handles multi-line "scripts" just fine. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You are right, there should be no such problem just because of multiple lines. However, when really inserting a shell script, it is likely there might be some `sed 's/foo/bar/'`, and therefore quoting might pose some problem here. The solution from jm666 just gives me the impression of being on the safe side. Thank you anyway!

Comment: No, it won't. The value of `$CMDS` can contain any character other than 0x00 NUL. The same goes for the parameters. I've added an example to my answer.